# WooCommerce Related Products only showing 2 products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got Related Products set up, but it's only showing 2.  I need it to show 5 across, but none of the code that I've tweaked has changed anything.

This is my related.php code:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->exists() ) {
    return;
}

$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );

if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 5,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

and this is the related products code on the single product page template:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <?php echo do_shortcode ( '[related_products per_page="5"]' ); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I think it's related to the filter `woocommerce_related_products_args`, it probably change the `posts_per_page` value. Could you check in your theme if there is any definition for this filter?

Comment: The only 'posts_per_page' defined is in the code I pasted above on related.php and it's set to 5.

Comment: I'm talking about the filter [`woocommerce_related_products_args`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_related_products_args/) - search for it instead of `posts_per_page` (the filter argument can be named in an other way).

Comment: Same result, only found in related.php above.

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump` of `$args` just before sending it to WP_Query, to see if `posts_per_page` is 5?

Comment: Would that look something like this?

echo var_dump($args);

Comment: Just `var_dump($args);` (`var_dump` do the `echo`).

Comment: ok, so i put var_dump($args); before $products = new WP_Query( $args );

where does that output to?  sorry, i've not had to get this in depth with it before.

Comment: When you refresh the page you should see the dump on top of your related products block.

Comment: nothing... http://function-4.com/product/bizhub3350/

Comment: Well then maybe _related.php_ is not the template that is being used. Maybe try to echo something, or comment the whole php to see if it change anything. Maybe it get overriden by a child theme?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a woocomerce child page and connect to that. The 'posts_per_page' => 5, has no control over what is currently displaying. The woocomerce page handles that.

```
Replace 
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
with
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'similarProductsFive' ); ?>
```

Then if you're using a child theme create a folder called "woocommerce" and place a file called "similarProductsFive.php" inside of it, or place the child woocommerce folder with that file inside your theme.

Then add this code to similarProuctFive.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

// Store loop count we're currently on
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;

// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );

// Ensure visibility
if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() )
    return;

// Increase loop count
$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;

// Extra post classes
$classes = array();
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes[] = 'first';
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes[] = 'last';
    $classes[] = "store-similar-products product";
?>
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

    </a>

    <?php

        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); 

    ?>

</li>
```

You can then change the amount of products displaying here:

```
$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 )
```